# Why does this runs loop one more time?

Tags: javascript

I'm running this code:

```js
var number = 0;
while (number <= 11) {
  console.log(number);
  number += 2;
}
```

But the output goes to 12. I've tried same with `for` loop the output was okay, till 10.

It tried it another way by replacing `console.log` with `console.warn` in `while` loop. The output *warns* till 10 but *logs* 12.

[image]

Further, by replacing `console` with `alert`, I got output till 10 in alert but still I see 12 in console.

[image]

Comment: 12 is printed by some other code

Comment: It should be noted that if you click the "run code snippet" button of your own post, it doesn't write 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console.log is not running one more time. In the console, it is just reporting the final value of number.

To prove this, simply prepend some text in `console.log` and you'll see.

```
var number = 0; 
while(number <= 11){   
    console.log("the output " + number);   
    number += 2; 
}
```

> [image]